# How to allow custom flash keys in a redirect_to call in Rails 3

Tags: redirect, ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails 3, you can pass has attributes directly to `redirect_to` to set the flash. For example:

```
redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Something was successful!"
```

However, this only works with the `:alert` and `:notice` keys; if you want to use custom keys, you have to use a more verbose version:

```
redirect_to root_path, :flash => { :error => "Something was successful!" }
```

Is there any way to make it so that custom keys (such as `:error`, above) can be passed to `redirect_to` without specifying it in `:flash => {}`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In Rails 4 you can do this

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  add_flash_types :error, ...
```

and then somewhere

```
redirect_to root_path, error: 'Some error'
```

http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/register-your-own-flash-types-rails-4-countdown-to-2013

Comment: Awesome! Marking this as the accepted answer as it should be used going forward.

Comment: im running into an issue where i called a flash type :login but i also have a helper method login from the "sorcery gem." maybe adding flash types with that is not so great at the moment?

Comment: Talking about performance or the right way to achieve the same behavior, what is the best way to go: **1.- Adding new flash types** as with `add_flash_types :error,...` or **2.- Adding new hashes in Flash object** as with `:flash => { :error => "Oh no!" }` ?

Answer (score 8):

I used the following code, placed in `lib/core_ext/rails/action_controller/flash.rb` and loaded via an initializer (it's a rewrite of the built-in Rails code):

```
module ActionController
  module Flash
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      delegate :alert, :notice, :error, :to => "request.flash"
      helper_method :alert, :notice, :error
    end

    protected
      def redirect_to(options = {}, response_status_and_flash = {}) #:doc:
        if alert = response_status_and_flash.delete(:alert)
          flash[:alert] = alert
        end

        if notice = response_status_and_flash.delete(:notice)
          flash[:notice] = notice
        end

        if error = response_status_and_flash.delete(:error)
          flash[:error] = error
        end

        if other_flashes = response_status_and_flash.delete(:flash)
          flash.update(other_flashes)
        end

        super(options, response_status_and_flash)
      end
  end
end
```

You can, of course, add more keys besides just `:error`; check the code at http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ead93c/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/flash.rb to see how the function looked originally.