# Trouble setting flash messages in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've forked a project on GitHub  that has some flash messages. For example, with Twitter sign in the project I forked comes with this red error message for failed sign in

```
  flash[:error] = "Sign in with Twitter failed"
```

I've also found the class in the CSS that makes it red. I want to use this error message elsewhere but I'm having problems.

For example, when I tried to do this

```
redirect_to show_path, flash[:error] => "Twitter's saying you're trying to post the same message twice"
```

It's simply not posting the message to Twitter and giving no error message. When I change
`=>` to `=` it breaks the whole application (when I try to post twice) giving me this message:

```
 can't convert Symbol into String
```

Even stranger (to me), I have no problem with :notice. This was fine.

```
redirect_to show_path, :notice => "Your Tweet was posted!"
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening?  [This is the project on GitHub](https://github.com/sferik/sign-in-with-twitter).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note how in your example with notice, you're using the raw `:notice` symbol in the hash arg of redirect_to instead of `flash[:notice]`. In your code with the error flash, you're trying to use `flash[:alert]`. You need to pass just the symbol, so try

```
redirect_to show_path, :error => "Twitter's saying you're trying to post the same message twice"
```

You can also set the alert flash prior to the redirect_to call:

```
flash[:error] = "Twitter's saying you're trying to post the same message twice"
redirect_to show_path
```

Comment: Actually, if you read my OP closely, I already tried your first solution, and noted that no error message at all was displayed.  However, the second solution worked.  Can you explain why the first one isn't working?

Comment: In your example, you're using `flash[:error] => "stuff"` in the redirect_to call. You need to use `:error => "stuff"`, without the flash.[] call.

Comment: The difference between these is that when you use `flash[:error] => "stuff"`, the key that goes into the hash argument is whatever the value of `flash[:error]` is - probably an empty string, unless you've explicitly set it beforehand. If you instead pass in `:error => "stuff"`, you're using the `:error` symbol itself for your key, instead of some mysterious value floating in `flash`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I agree. I got nothing when I do :   redirect_to show_path, :success => "Your Tweet was posted"

Comment: `:alert` and `:notice` are the only custom flash accessors you can use directly in `redirect_to`. According to the rails API info [link](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000468), there's also a general `:flash` accessor you can use, that seems to work like this: `redirect_to some_path, :flash => { :success => "Stuff" }` for general flash access. I haven't tested this, though, so YMMV. However, using `flash[:success] = "Stuff"; redirect_to some_path` is always available, as well.

Comment: Oh, it seems @bassneck posted about that already. Missed it when I noticed the comment here.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, I've been there too :)

@jsinger is partially right. You need to pass a symbol instead of the `flash[]` hash. But there's a catch: redirec_to supports only two shorthand symbols: `:notice` and `:alert`. There is a third, a general one: `:flash`.

```
redirect_to show_path, :flash => { :success/:error/:whatever => "your flash message" }
```

I wonder what reasoning is behind this.

[APIdock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/redirect_to)

Comment: It's probably just simpler to have a simpler interface it can use for the general case using the bucket syntax, something like `args[:flash].each {|k, v| flash[k] = v}`. But if you have a small subset of valid types that are very common in use (:notice and :alert, apparently), having the shortcut straight to them can save a decent amount of time/code.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying. Bucket may be a nice stuff if you need to set several flash params, but I have never used it. On the other hand, I use success, error and notice in every project + alert sometimes. It would be a bit simpler, if I could just write `redirect_to ..., :success => "well done!"` :)

Comment: Yea. Maybe be the Rails devs like :notice and :alert a lot? Who knows. Actually, looking at the api [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash/FlashHash.html), notice and alert are the only FlashHash options that have built in accessors, and then it accepts any arbitrary symbols later on. If that's the case, then I guess it makes sense - :success, etc. are just conventions used by the community. Maybe older versions only allowed :notice and :alert specifically, so it grew from that? I've only been messing around with Rails for a couple days, so idk.

Comment: Oh, hey, Googling around I found it straight from the dev who put it in: "I was looking over the code in a new application and kept seeing this pattern. Then I looked at a bunch of other applications. Probably 80-90% of all flash usage in these applications followed this pattern of setting a notice or an alert just before a redirect. This embraces that pattern and makes it first class." [Source (DHH in the commends)](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/12/20/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-set-flash-in-redirect_to)

Comment: If you really want to add other "magic keys" [it can be done](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848755/how-to-allow-custom-flash-keys-in-a-redirect-to-call-in-rails-3).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

flash.now[:notice] = "some text"