# What flash message types are available in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So far I've got:

- :notice
- :alert
- :error

but is there definitive list, that can be used in place, such as in `redirect_to path, :error => "Oh no!"`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No, as a flash type you can use any symbol, even your own.

Comment: As Steve Grossi points out below, you can't pass any symbol to `redirect_to` as in the example that cjm2671 uses.

Answer (score 99):

Hauleth is correct that you can use any symbol, but right now, `:notice` and `:alert` are the only ones you can pass **directly** into `redirect_to` (according to [flash.rb in Rails source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/flash.rb)), as you specifically mention:

```
redirect_to path, :error => "Oh no!" # Will not work
```

If you want a different flash type such as `:error` (or `:success`), you must pass those in through the `:flash` key, like so:

```
redirect_to path, :flash => { :error => "Oh no!" }
```

For information on how to register your custom flash types so that, like `:notice` and `:alert`, you can pass them directly in to `redirect_to`, see this StackOverflow Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3848759/995663

**Update:** According to [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/238a4253bf229377b686bfcecc63dda2b59cff8f), it seems Rails 4 will make this easier by allowing you to register custom flash types by calling `add_flash_types :error` in ApplicationController.

Comment: Talking about performance or the right way to achieve the same behavior, what is the best way to go: **1.- Adding new flash types** as with `add_flash_types :error,...` or **2.- Adding new hashes in Flash object** as with `:flash => { :error => "Oh no!" }` ?

Answer (score 0):

The types of flash messages are, starting with the most urgent & decreasing:

```
flash[:danger]
flash[:warning]
flash[:info]
flash[:success]
```

While you can use any label within the flash[], the above mentioned labels are supported by Bootstrap CSS, meaning the key :success will automatically convert to the string "success" as well.

Comment: Looks like a good answer.  It would be even better with some links out to docs for this.